# Labeling elements to differentiate

Tags: styled-components

When using devtools, the classnames are sometimes difficult to differentiate.

Emotion js has here a good solution: https://emotion.sh/docs/labels

Basically they use the "Label" Property in css to append that to the generated class name.

Here some examples:

`css-a281on-some-name
css-1i3s76n-another-name`

Does something like this exists for styled-components?
I could not find it.
If not, I would make a feature request.

Comment: Here is the PR for emotions implementation> https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/pull/375

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the [`babel` plugin for `styled-components`](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/tooling#babel-plugin). If the component `ABC` is created with `styled-components` in the file `SomeFile.js`, the class name for that component will look like `SomeFile__ABC-fBdEtY JrIAq`. Add the plugin to your `babel` config, either in `.babelrc` or in `options.plugins` in `babel-loader` if you use `webpack`.

Comment: This is indeed what I needed. I use Gatsby and this plugin helped me point to this babel plugin: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/@raygesualdo/gatsby-plugin-babel-styled-components/